# How can I achieve a Google Doc-like effect on Meteor? (real-time update text)

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming

I'm wondering, whats a good way to build an effect where the text I type is updated in real time? Like in Google Docs, when sharing a document, both sides see the same changes as the person types, without submitting at all. For example, can I observe a change using jquery and update a collection on every button press? Wouldn't that mean a whole lot of server calls (sounds bad to me). Any other ideas?

Comment: Look at `websockets`

Answer (score 2):

The effect, operational transformation, isn't part of Meteor yet. It's on the roadmap (http://roadmap.meteor.com).

The effect isn't as simple as it may seem, its better to use a 3rd party library to do it.

While meteor doesn't have it officially there is a ShareJS package for Meteor that can do this:

Added with

```
meteor add mizzao:sharejs
```

More details on the github repo: https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-sharejs